# How do iptables policies work?

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, firewall, ubuntu-12.04

I've added some basic rules:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Then, command to close all other ports with:

```
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

And it works perfectly, I tested it with:

```
% telnet x.x.x.x 81                                
Trying x.x.x.x...
telnet: connect to address x.x.x.x: Operation timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

But when I list rules, I see `policy ACCEPT`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

I know how to change it, with `iptables -P INPUT DROP`, then it becomes:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

But I don't understand the difference, because it works as before. I've read [this](http://gr8idea.info/os/tutorials/security/iptables4.html) article which suggests to change the policy to DROP, but why should I do that? What is the difference in my iptables above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An iptables DROP policy is equivalent to `iptables -A INPUT -j DROP` (DROP rule) at the end of the chain. But this rule *must stay at the end of the chain*, any rule after it will never get touched by any packet.

If you use the DROP rule, you cannot anymore use `iptables -A` (append), you can only use `iptables -I nr` (insert, nr is the number of the last rule) and insert rules before the last one. And for this insert to work you must know the rule number of your last rule, which of course will change, so it becomes more difficult to script. You can save you some difficulties by using the DROP policy.

And lastly imho it makes the whole far more readable, if I know from the beginn how packets that do not match any rule will be handeld.

Any other thoughts about this?

Comment: Thank you! I've just wanted to post own answer, I removed last rule(DROP all anywhere) and with policy DROP it still blocks all other ports, so the article is misleading

Comment: @RustamA.Gasanov, yes, drop policy is here for this. In fact the DROP policy is the correct way to go, especially on INPUT: forbid anything, but only allow what you want to allow. Note also that only built-in chains have can have a policy, custom chain that you define cannot.